# Intercept button click with jQuery from iframe to other iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, velo

I'm using `wix` to create simple landing page and would like to connect it with `google analytics` events.

I would like to intercept the event of pushing form send button.

[Page example with form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7SFJ.png)

The button id -> `submitButton`

Normally if i have full access to page code i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#buttonName').click(function () {     
                 //google function                         
                 ga('send', 'event', 'EventCategory', 'EventCategory', 'EventName'); 
              });
       }); 
</script>
```

But here I can use only iFrame an internal plugin (hat generate code inside iframe).

> PAGE STRUCTURE:
>   - Text, image ecc ecc; 
>   - iFrame with form (managed by plugin, where i can't add/edit code); 
>   - iFrame where i can add code.
>  for example: [example page](http://www.sigolomotors.it/#!promozione-tagliando-2015/aggma)

So I need to invoke click event of the button  with id `submitButton` from an `iframe` which invokes the click of the button placed in other `iframe` (where the id is unknown).

is there a way to do that?
Thank you for response.

Comment: So your saying you don't have access to the modal/iframe markup to embed the JS click event?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the iFrame code you will not be able to put that tracking id the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to intercept a click event within the iframe that you **don't** have control of, I'm pretty sure that's not possible for security reasons: otherwise it would be possible for an advert or any third party code on your page to intercept events on completely unrelated elements.

If you're trying to pass a click event from a bit you **do** control to a button that you don't, unless you know the ID of the button in the other iFrame you want to click, I don't think you're going to have much luck.

Comment: something change if i have other frame id and button id?

Comment: Well, you can select an element within an Iframe provided you know what it's called. if your DOM structure is such that you have access to the parent of the IFrame you could use 
<parentname>.<IFramename>.document.getElementById("<elementname>").<whatever it is you want to do> , and I'm pretty sure that would have the effect you want.